# QBO3 - Why did my Attachment / Generate to FTP site fail?

Tags: ftp, mailmerge

We have an Attachment/Generate job that creates daily delta files associated with our Organization record, saving these files to our corporate FTP server. Occasionally, the job appears to fail, as evidence by "missing" documents under our Organization.

Here is a picture of the panel with the missing documents:
[image: Documents Panel]

How do I find the root cause of the job failure?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways it could have gone missing.  The first we can check is if the schedule job is still ready to be processed for the next day.
This (like all of the scheduled queued items) can be found Dashboards -> Queued Items
From the far right drop down select both Show Active and Show Future:

[image: Options for Queued Items Search Panel]

Then navigate in the Search panel and select the item you are looking at such as:

[image: Scheduled Daily Delta Item]

A quick breakdown

1. The Attachment Template is shown for how the Daily Delta is created
2. The Queue is shown which processes the item
3. The Queued Date which is the next time this item will run
4. The Schedule that is set for this item so that it will determine when to run in the future after it has executed.

If the delta did not run or there was an error the best place to locate that currently is in the Queue Logs.

Go to Design -> Configuration and select queuing from the left hand side panel.  Then Select the Queue Failure Link on the Default Queue row.  This will bring up a new panel that will be similar to below.  For this particular research put in Generate into the search box for Operation and hit Enter.

[image: Default Queue Failure Log]

You can see where the FTP errors occurred in the past via this panel.